# EMQX Broker Starting Error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mqtt, emq, emqx

I'm quite new to using EMQX MQTT broker.
I ran installation successfully using the commands as given [here](https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/v5/deploy/install-ubuntu.html#install-with-deb):
`curl -s https://assets.emqx.com/scripts/install-emqx-deb.sh | sudo bash`
`sudo apt-get install emqx`

After this, i started the newly installed EMQX broker using the command:
`sudo emqx start`

which resulted to the following error:

```
WARNING: Default (insecure) Erlang cookie is in use.
WARNING: Configure node.cookie in /etc/emqx/emqx.conf or override from environment variable EMQX_NODE__COOKIE
WARNING: NOTE: Use the same cookie for all nodes in the cluster.
ERROR: EMQX 5.2.0-build.1 using node name 'emqx@127.0.0.1' failed 120 probes.
```

I kindly request any of your assistance please, in case you've bumped in such error.
Thank you!

I tried running the installation as given in this [guide](https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/v2.0/install.html#download-packages)

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for the potential solutions to this, I got this to start the EMQX broker:

```
sudo systemctl start emqx
```

Worked for me!